Jetty 12.0.12 throwing exception while creating new Jetty Server()
After updating jetty-server to 12.0.12 from 11.0.24,Testcase is failing while creating MockServer.
Error: NoSuchMethod 'boolean org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.installBean(java.lang.Object)'
class MockServer :
        Server(0),
        AutoCloseable {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    
        private val ports: List<Int>
            get() = this.connectors.filterIsInstance(ServerConnector::class.java).map { it.localPort }
    
        val url: String
            get() = "http://localhost:${ports.first()}"
    
        override fun doStart() {
            super.doStart()
            logger.info("Started at $url")
        }
    
        override fun close() {
            if (isStarted) {
                logger.info("Stopping at $url")
                stop()
            }
        }
    }

Testcase:
@Test
    fun `test HTTP endpoints`() =
    withResources {
        val cfg =
            mockConfiguration(
               ''
            )

        val tst = Mockito.mock(ClientObj::class.java)
        Mockito.doReturn(Mockito.mock(FServer::class.java)).`when`(tst).newServer(any(), any())
        MockDataSource().use { db ->
            MockServer().use { server ->
                Main.start(cfg, tst, db.dataSource(), server, Mockito.mock(Helper::class.java))
                server.start()
                
                withProvider(server.url + "/service") { provider ->
                    val client = Service.Client(provider)


                    client.ping(mockContext())
                    assertEquals('HEALTHY', client.getHealth(mockContext()).status)

                }
            }
        }
    }


NoSuchMethod 'boolean org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.installBean(java.lang.Object)'

How to solve this? Am I missing a dependency? I found it hard to see what dependencies I needed for a basic jetty 12 server.
